# How to read comments from XML file using DOM parser

Tags: java, dom

I'm trying to read the comments in an XML file. Not able to get the comment nodes after parsing it with DOM.

Code:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory docBldrFactry = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
docBldrFactry.setIgnoringComments(false);
DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docBldrFactry.newDocumentBuilder();
Document document = docBuilder.parse(new File("C:\\webser.xml"));
Element rootElement = document.getDocumentElement();
NodeList list = rootElement.getElementsByTagName("Bean");
```

Comments are under Bean element. WHen I loop through the child nodes of Bean element, I don't get the comment nodes.

Here is the XML

```
<Beans>
  <Bean>
    <!-- Testing Comments -->
    <API name ="xyz" />
  </Bean>
</Beans>
```

Comment: You aren't getting the comments in your parsed structure because they're comments - parenthetical notes meant for reading, rather than interaction with code. Take a look at [this duplicate question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/994773/can-dom-parsers-read-inside-html-comments-or-is-regex-the-only-way) for some ideas on how to read the values in the comment nodes.

Comment: See .. that was my understanding too.. But while reading about this topic.. I came to know that DOM has a comments node type (#8).. How and when these will be created or read? Will it be only for creating comments?

Comment: You should tag your question with the language you are using - looks like Java to me, but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 5):

Hope this helps :)

```
XMLStreamReader xr = XMLInputFactory.newInstance().createXMLStreamReader(new FileInputStream("file.xml")); 
while (xr.hasNext()) {
    if (xr.next() == XMLStreamConstants.COMMENT) {
        String comment = xr.getText();
    } }
```