# Parsing XML comments with DOM

Tags: java, xml, parsing, dom, xml-parsing

I need to parse XML Tags which are commented out like

```
<DataType Name="SecureCode" Size="4" Type="NVARCHAR">
    <!-- <Validation>
            <Regex JavaPattern="^[0-9]*$" JSPattern="^[0-9]*$"/>
    </Validation> -->
    <UIType Size="4" UITableSize="4"/>
</DataType>
```

But all I found was `setIgnoringComments(boolean)`

```
Document doc = docBuilder.parse(new File(PathChecker.getDataTypesFile()));
docFactory.setIgnoringComments(true); // ture or false, no difference
```

But it doesn't seem to change anything.
Is there any other way to parse this comments? I have to use DOM.

Regards

Comment: Possible duplicate of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12069509/how-to-read-comments-from-xml-file-using-dom-parser

Comment: I've also found that post. It doesn't help me in any way.

Comment: It appears that setIgnoringComments() has a bug, it has been reported, but no fix has been made in all these years: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/XERCESJ-37

Comment: setIgnoringComments() just worked for me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Method "setIgnoringComments" removed comments from DOM tree during parsing.
With "setIgnoringComments(false)" you can get comment text like:

```
    NodeList nl = doc.getDocumentElement().getChildNodes();
    for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
        if (nl.item(i).getNodeType() == Element.COMMENT_NODE) {
            Comment comment=(Comment) nl.item(i);
            System.out.println(comment.getData());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Oh that's cool. Didn't tried it but that should solve it. Thanks

Comment: This will not pick single-line comments.

Answer (score 0):

Since there seems not to exist a "regular way" of solving the problem I've just removed the comments.

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(PathChecker.getDataTypesFile())));
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new File(PathChecker.getDataTypesFileWithoutComments())));

String line = "";

while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    line = line.replace("<!--", "").replace("-->", "") + "\n";
    bw.write(line);
}
```