# Sort XML file in Groovy without loosing comments

Tags: xml, groovy

I have XML file in below format

```
<solutions>
    <!--This is permanent Comment-->
    <solution solutionName="XYZ.1052">
        <settings/>
    </solution>
    <solution solutionName="XYZ.1012">
        <settings/>
    </solution>
    <solution solutionName="XYZ.1053">
        <settings/>
    </solution>
</solutions>
```

I want to sort it without loosing comments. So expected output is:

```
<solutions>
    <solution solutionName="XYZ.1012">
        <settings/>
    </solution>
    <!--This is permanent Comment-->
    <solution solutionName="XYZ.1052">
        <settings/>
    </solution>
    <solution solutionName="XYZ.1053">
        <settings/>
    </solution>
</solutions>
```

I am trying with xmlparser, xmlslurpur and DomBuilder but no luck yet.

Comment: Please post your current code

Comment: `xmlparser` and `xmlslurpur` do not support xml comments. you could use java standard dom parser. for example:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12069509/how-to-read-comments-from-xml-file-using-dom-parser

Comment: Do you want the comments to move or to stay in exactly the same spot after sorting?

Comment: They should move with their respective nodes. I have shown it in above example